# Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range: item length 0 but minimum is 1 on React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I know this has been asked before and I've tried everything I've seen so far, but it still producing the same error. What I am trying to achieve is to offset the carousel so that it is center on the screen when I scroll to an item.

Here's the error `Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range: item length 0 but minimum is 1`

Here's the component

```
import React, {useContext, useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { colors } from '../assets/theme/config';
import { ThemeContext } from '../context/ThemeContext';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const ITEM_SIZE = 160;
const SPACING = 10;

const CarouselRow = ({data, label, english, navigation}) => {

  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [viewPosition, setViewPosition] = useState(0.5);
  const [waza, setWaza] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.scrollToIndex({
      index, 
      animated: true,
      viewPosition: viewPosition,
      viewOffset: ITEM_SIZE * 0.5
    });

    setWaza([...data])
  }, [index, viewPosition])


  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={[{color:activeColors.primary}, styles.sectionheading]}> 
        {label} 
      </Text>
      <Text style={{color:activeColors.textcolor, fontSize:14, fontWeight:"normal", marginBottom:10}}>{english}</Text>
    
      <Animated.FlatList
        ref={ref}
        data={waza}
        horizontal
        contentOffset = {{x: ITEM_SIZE * 0.25, y: 0}}
        initialScrollIndex={index}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
        decelerationRate={0}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        onEndReached={() => {
          setWaza([...waza, ...data]);
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
        renderItem={
          ({item, index: fIndex}) => {
            const inputRange = [
              ITEM_SIZE * (fIndex - 2),
              ITEM_SIZE * (fIndex - 1),
              ITEM_SIZE * fIndex,
            ];

            const translateY = scrollX.interpolate({
              inputRange,
              outputRange: [0, -20, 0]
            });

            return (
              <TouchableOpacity 
                key={fIndex}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TechniqueDetails', {data: item})}
                style={{width:ITEM_SIZE}}>      
                <Animated.View 
                  style={[{transform:[{translateY}]}, styles.itemcont]}>         
                  <Image source={{ uri: `https://judopedia.wiki/assets/images/${item.thumbnail}` }} 
                  style={styles.thumbnail}/>
                  <Text 
                    numberOfLines={2}
                    style={{
                      width: ITEM_SIZE - 10,
                      color:activeColors.textcolor, 
                      fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }}>  
                    {item.title} 
                  </Text>   
                </Animated.View>   
              </TouchableOpacity>   
            )
          }
        }
      />
  </View>
  )
}

export default CarouselRow

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  thumbnail: {
    width: ITEM_SIZE - 10,
    height: 220,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  itemcont: {
    marginHorizontal: SPACING,
    padding: SPACING * 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 34,
  },
  sectionheading:{
    fontWeight: 'bold', 
    fontSize: 22, 
    paddingBottom: 0,
    paddingTop: 20,    
  },
})
```

Notice in the screenshot, the first item is located at the left:0 which is normal, but with ViewOffset, I can move the slider so that it splits the view at 50% of the screen. I'm using the scrollToIndex to capture that first item. I'm wondering if it doesn't work because I am looping the carousel?

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: Initialize index with 1 instead of 0 ```const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);```

Comment: I tried that first. Sorry I should've mentioned